# Probability distribution to maximize the expected distance between two points

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, metric-spaces, expected-value

Let $M$ be some metric space. We will also say that $M$ is a [measurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space).

How do you find a probability measure $P$ on $M$ that maximizes the expected distance between two points? (That is, $P$ maximizes $E[d(X,Y)]$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with distribution $P$.)

If $M$ is a discrete metric, then $P$ will the uniform distribution, for example.

Note that we can think of this as a game, and $P$ as a [mixed strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_(game_theory)#Mixed_strategy). You would have two players, which are both trying to maximize the distance. This is not a purely game-theoretical situation though, since we need to require the players to pick the same strategy. There is something called *superrationality* that might apply, but it is not well studied though. Maybe techniques similar to those used in game theory could be used though.

Comment: You need a measure on $M^2$ (i.e. the joint distribution of 2 random points on $M$).

Comment: @d.k.o. wouldn't that just be a product space of $M$ with itself?

Comment: Do you mean the product measure $P\otimes P$? Maybe, if you assume independence.

Comment: @d.k.o. yes, I want to assume they are i.d.d. Otherwise, you could just pick to points that are a diameter apart, and always choose them. The point is that you need to choose randomly, because if you don't, the expected distance is guaranteed to be $0$.

Comment: Makes sense. I think you need to include this info in the question.

Comment: @d.k.o. Okay, I edited the question. Is it well formed and does it make more sense now?

Comment: $Ed (X,Y)$ can be $\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes

Comment: Very interesting question, but it depends a lot on the details of the metric space. If your space is $\{0,\pm1\}$, though, with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, I think the optimum is to pick $\pm1$ uniformly, not to pick all 3 points uniformly, though.

Comment: @kimchilover - I imagine your observation can be generalized:  If the space is a real interval $[a,b]$, and $d(x,y)  = |x-y|$, the optimum is to pick $a,b$ uniformly.  This seems "obvious" but I can't prove it...  Your thoughts?

Comment: @kimchilover - But $1/2 > 1/3$ so my proposal works.  Sorry if my last comment wasn't clear: I meant to pick among just the two endpoints $\{a,b\}$ uniformly, i.e. with $1/2$ prob each.  (Just like how you picked from $\pm 1$ and ignored the $0$.  Indeed if endpoint picking optimizes the $[-1, 1]$ interval case, it also obviously optimizes the $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ case, which is why I call it a generalization.)

Comment: @antkam  Sorry: I misread your comment.  You might be right.  I'll try to think about this.